# Is there a function defined on an interval that is right-differentiable a.e. but not left-differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Inspired by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342427), I was thinking about how different the left and right sided derivatives could be at a point. For instance, if $f(x) = e^{-1/\log(x)}$, $f(1)=0$, the right derivative at $x=1$ is zero but the left-derivative doesn't exist. One could stitch together several of these functions, for instance $F_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n f(x-k)$, but I'm wondering if this pathology can be extended to yield a function $F$ that is right-differentiable almost-everywhere but left-differentiable almost-nowhere.

Happy to provide clarification or more details if needed.

Comment: Well , Is the function  continuous ?(+1) for the nice example .

Comment: I *think* if the function is continuous then at best we get a countable set of discontinuities, so then $F$ is differentiable a.e. So we might need $F$ discontinuous.

Comment: A lot of information on this topic is given in my answer to [Real-valued function of one variable which is continuous on $[a,b]$ and semi-differentiable on $[a,b)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128820/13130) In summary, such an exceptional set can be uncountable (in fact, it can have cardinality continuum; see the paragraph just before the references in my just cited answer), but any such exceptional set must be small in other ways (has Lebesgue measure zero and is meager in the Baire category sense), and thus the answer to your question is NO.